# Is it possible to add "range" (ie.max-min) to the pandas describe function in python?

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to add "range" (ie.max-min) to the pandas describe function in python?

I would like to get like this ?

```
     sepal_length   sepal_width
count    150            150
mean     5.843333       3.054
std      0.828066       0.433594
min      4.3            2
25%      5.1            2.8
50%      5.8            3
75%      6.4            3.3
max      7.9            4.4
Range    3.6            2.4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think simpliest is add to output subtracting rows and wrap to function:

```
def describe_new(df):
    df1 = df.describe()
    df1.loc["range"] = df1.loc['max'] - df1.loc['min']
    return df1

print (describe_new(df))
```

Comment: i just wanted to know whether pandas describe function can be modified to include user defined  function? example in the above case is range

Comment: Unfortunately not, only is possible create new function.

Comment: See [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) - not supported

Comment: Please [mark an answer as correct](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it resolved your question. This helps us keep track of which questions are left to be answered.